# Rename photos, jpg ordering based on raw times

Tags: batch, filenames, exif

I have a large set of photos taken with both JPG and RAW which are named in wrong order since the camera counter reset after about half of them. While going through the JPG files I turned some of them CW or CCW. Unfortunately this altered the timestamp of the photos.

What I want to do is to use the timestamp of the RAW file to create a new name for both the JPG and the RAW file since the RAW file timestamp is unaltered.

For example, I have

```
DSC_250.jpg (taken 05:00, not true)
DSC_250.nef (taken 01:00, correct time)
DSC_100.jpg (taken 03:00, correct time)
DSC_100.nef (taken 03:00, correct time)
```

And want this to be:

```
DSC_001.jpg (taken 01:00)
DSC_001.nef (taken 01:00)
DSC_002.jpg (taken 03:00)
DSC_002.nef (taken 03:00)
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the only way to do what you say is to write a custom program.

You might be better off to go back to your archive of the photos before you altered them (you do keep originals don't you?) and use a better program to rotate them.

I use "Picture Information Extractor" for things like this.  It's possible that the internal metadata contains the original date, and a program like PIE would be able to set the file date back to match the internal date.

Comment: I started over from scratch and used a combo of PIE and another batch renamer to get what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of naming the photos with an index it's more efficient to rename with a time-stamp. This gives you also the possibility mix your with pictures from another camera and still get them sorted by time.

```
DSC_250.jpg -> 2014.03.05-01.00.00.jpg
DSC_250.nef -> 2014.03.05-01.00.00.nef
DSC_100.jpg -> 2014.03.05-03.00.00.jpg
DSC_100.nef -> 2014.03.05-03.00.00.nef
```

There is a number of different software that does this. Chrono Namer is free you can down load it from http://chrononamer.com.